# Accepting inputs to append to list/dictionary depending on whether data is present on both sides of chosen value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split, append

I'm attempting to create a list (or dictionary, unsure which is more appropriate) which will have values I have input. It will only append inputted values if it follows the correct format, which is two numbers separated by ';' (123;456, 1334;451, etc), and then splits the two numbers. How can I do this? `newlist = [x.split(';') for x in list if x]` is what I've done but the output comes out as `[['123', '456'], ['1334', '451']`, which is correct in a sense but if I was to input just `123;;` that would have been accepted.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can put some regular expression, for example `import re
[x.split(';;') for x in my_list if re.match('.+;;.+',x) ]`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a check in that list comprehension to replace `if x` with `if len(x.split('::')) == 2`. This will only include elements which have values on both sides of your delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

To reject e.g. `"789;;abc"`, use [.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
import re
from pprint import pp

s = "789;;abc apple 123;;101 banana 122;;324 cherry 090;;089 date"

two_nums_re = re.compile(r"(\d+);;(\d+)")
pp(two_nums_re.findall(s), width=16)
```

That produces:

```
[('123', '101'),
 ('122', '324'),
 ('090', '089')]
```

---

You can easily substitute an alternate delimiter if desired.

```
>>> " ".join(f"{a}::{b}" for a, b in two_nums_re.findall(s))
'123::101 122::324 090::089'
```